# How to debug autowired interface in configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class XDDeliveryConfig {

    @Value("${direct.gateway.xd.endpointUrl: http://localhost:8080/xd/services/DocumentRepository_Service}")
    protected String endpointURL;

    @Autowired
    protected RoutingResolver resolver;

    @Autowired
    protected XDDeliveryCallback xdDeliveryCallback;

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public XDDeliveryCore xdDeliveryCore() {
        final ReliableDispatchedNotificationProducer notificationProducer =
            new ReliableDispatchedNotificationProducer(
                new NotificationSettings(true, "Direct XD Delivery Agent",
                        "Your message was successfully dispatched."));

        return new XDDeliveryCore(
                resolver, xdDeliveryCallback, new DefaultTxDetailParser(),
                new DefaultMimeXdsTransformer(), new DocumentRepository(), 
                notificationProducer, endpointURL);
    }
}
```

Which for some reason has a problem with the autowired `XDDeliveryCallback` interface which looks like:

```
public interface XDDeliveryCallback {
    void sendNotificationMessage(NotificationMessage message) throws MessagingException;
}
```

And constructor for the `XDDeliveryCore` class looks like:

```
public class XDDeliveryCore {
    protected final RoutingResolver resolver;
    protected final XDDeliveryCallback callback;
    protected final TxDetailParser txParser;
    protected final MimeXdsTransformer mimeXDSTransformer;
    protected final DocumentRepository documentRepository;
    protected final NotificationProducer notificationProducer;
    protected final String endpointUrl;

    public XDDeliveryCore(RoutingResolver resolver, XDDeliveryCallback callback,
                          TxDetailParser txParser,
                          MimeXdsTransformer mimeXDSTransformer, DocumentRepository documentRepository,
                          NotificationProducer notificationProducer, String endpointUrl) {
        this.resolver = resolver;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.txParser = txParser;
        this.mimeXDSTransformer = mimeXDSTransformer;
        this.endpointUrl = endpointUrl;
        this.documentRepository = documentRepository;
        this.notificationProducer = notificationProducer;
    }

}
```

How can I debug why `callback` in the `XDDeliveryCore` is `null` or what I have missed?

PS.
Implementation for the interface:

```
@Configuration
public class XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor implements XDDeliveryCallback {

    @Autowired
    protected XDDeliveryCore deliveryCore;

    @Autowired
    protected SmtpGatewayMessageSource smtpMessageSource;

    @Autowired
    protected DSNCreator dsnCreator;

    @Bean
    public Consumer<Message<?>> directXDDeliveryInput() {
        return streamMsg -> {
            try {
                final SMTPMailMessage smtpMessage = SMTPMailMessageConverter.fromStreamMessage(streamMsg);

                log.debug("XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor processing message from " + smtpMessage.getMailFrom().toString());
                deliveryCore.processAndDeliverXDMessage(smtpMessage);
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }

    public void sendNotificationMessage(NotificationMessage message) throws MessagingException {
        smtpMessageSource.sendMimeMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide `xdDeliveryCallback` as a formal parameter to `xdDeliveryCore()`, not as an autowired field.

Comment: @tgdavies I have tried that but I have got something like that bean cannot be autowired or instantiated, something like that

Comment: What is the implementation of the `XDDeliveryCallback` interface?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis added to the OP

Comment: @tgdavies your solution worked with fixed configuration class

Comment: @JackTheKnife Good job! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to autowire a bean, an instance of the `XDDeliveryCallback` interface. Though the `XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor` is the implementation of the interface, it is not registered as a Spring bean (I assume there is no XML configuration as your code seems fully annotation based).

The solution is to either register a bean in the XML configuration using `<bean class=... >` element or rather annotate the `XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor` implementation with `@Component`/`@Service`.

As long as the bean is properly scanned (using `@SpringBootApplication`/`@Configuration` or `<context:component-scan base-package=... >`), the bean is registered and the autowiring successful.

```java
@Component
public class XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor implements XDDeliveryCallback {

    // implementation
}
```

Remember the Spring annotations (such as `@Autowired`, `@Bean`, etc.) take no effect if the class is not registered as a proper Spring bean on configuration.

Comment: Sure, I will check if the Spring app picks that configuration file.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that `XDRemoteDeliveryProcessor` has `@Configuration` annotation too. Not sure if that is the main problem

Comment: So `@Cofiguration` `XDDeliveryConfig` is getting picked up when Spring boot application starts but autowired `XDDeliveryCallback ` is still null even `@Component` annotation was added.

Comment: Even I have added explicit component scan `@ComponentScan(value = "org.nhind.xd.streams")` and still is not autowire `XDDeliveryCallback`

Comment: It looks like it is Spring Boot "thing" that `XDeliveryCallback` was not initialized on time when the configuration class was scanned. `DependsOn` annotation will work fine on a bean, not an interface. Had a hard time getting `@Order` and `@ConditionalOnClass` to work in my case but getting config scanned + providing `xdDeliveryCallback` as a formal parameter to `xdDeliveryCore()` did the job.

Comment: Regarding debugging it Spring Boot application must know where to scan for configurations. Otherwise, it will not reflect during the app start.